# Swagger implemetation Spring Web MVC not display model Schema

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-maven-plugin

I am trying to implementing Spring Web MVC with Swagger but problem is I could not getting model Schema.
I am attaching code with question which is given blow.
I'm following the below link:

http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/documenting_your_spring_api_with

the issue was that Swagger UI was displaying but for the post request it was not displaying the model schema.

POM.XML:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring.xml:

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ga" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <bean id="documentationConfig" class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.DocumentationConfig" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/application.properties"
        system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />
```

Customer Controller.java:

```java
@Api(value="CustomerController",description="Customer Controller")
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

    @ApiOperation(value="save",notes="These Method is used to Save all Customer Details with its Deployment ")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> saveCustomerDetails(@RequestBody Customer customer) throws CustomerException {

    }
}
```

Application properties:

```
documentation.services.version=1.0
documentation.services.basePath=http://localhost:9090/XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution of the above issue.I just configure the swagger in my code internally.

i followed these link to configure the swagger.
[https://github.com/ufasoli/spring-mvc-swagger-tutorial.](https://github.com/ufasoli/spring-mvc-swagger-tutorial)

These really works for me.